# Front end development best practices

Tags: web-frontend

I want to build a web application. I'm wondering how I can find the best practices for front end development.

Comment: By googling "best practices for front end development".

Comment: Asking for external resources (books, tutorials, etc.) is off-topic here, and I'm thinking that some documentation on best practices (if there really is such a thing...) falls into that category. Plus... this is all subjective/opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a general question.And Full answer to this question should be a big article that i will not be able to add in answer.But i can include some information that is useful.There will be lot of Information available on Web to learn and do best practice for Front end developer.Most of best practice you will learn by following blogs and by your own practice.

Few Tips that i would add are below.

- Correct Syntax Makes Beautiful Code
- Testing Your Site in Different Resolutions of screen size Desktop and Mobile
- Test site using different Environments and browsers
- Think about Future usability of the Site
- Try to make it more responsive,fast and User friendly

Here are few Helpful Articles

http://www.sitepoint.com/20-docs-guides-front-end-developers/

http://taitems.github.io/Front-End-Development-Guidelines/

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-for-front-end-web-developers

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Comment: @garry - I have no idea why you'd answer a question like this that's completely off-topic. Plus link-only answers are really bad (and often deleted) because the links rot and die. Finally: Someone's blog post about what practices were useful to the author (catswhocode) or a dev team (isobar) do *not* equate to any type of official best practice.